# How to get time remaining on an NSTimer as a double

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am creating a very simple game where a I need to use the amount of time left before the timer fires in seconds so that I am able to convert it into a double. I have thought about using .fireDate but I don't think there is an easy way to convert it to a double. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timer.fireDate.timeIntervalSinceNow` should return the number of seconds remaining until the timer fires as an `NSTimeInterval` which is a `Double`

Comment: Thank you it works!